# regex validation for range of Numbers or alphabets A and D

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created regex expressions from an online regular expression generator web site. But none of them are working. What changes should I make in them? Please help!!!

for range of number between [0 - 30] or either A or D,

input [0,1,2,...,30] is valid but it is validating numbers above 30 also. Similarly with all the regex validating numbers above the maximum range too.

```
Regex.IsMatch(dr["ECO"].ToString(), @"([0-9]|[12][0-9]|30|A|D)$")
```

for range of number between [0 - 25] or either A or D

```
Regex.IsMatch(dr["GEOGRAPHY"].ToString(), @"(^(2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[1-9])|A|D)$")
```

for range of number between [1 - 20] or either A or D

```
Regex.IsMatch(dr["HEALTH_SCI"].ToString(), @"([0-9]|1[0-9]|20|A|D)$")
```

The regular expressions shows valid in some online tester too, but in C# these regex are not working. What is the problem? Please help!!!

Comment: It's hard to help you understand what's going wrong without the inputs to your regex methods.

Comment: Your expected input is not clear. Please edit and add examples that should pass validation and examples that should not

Comment: Also, you're inconsistent with the anchors you're using. #2 uses Start and End of string anchors, but the others use only End.

Comment: Also be sure to use a C# regex generator tool. Not all languages use the exact same rules.

Comment: @AleksAndreev I have edited my question. Actually the problem is that all the regex are allowing numbers greater than the range. I mean the regex for 1 - 20 is validating number above 20 also. Please help!!!

Comment: @Jasen Where can I find the C# regex generator tool. Please provide the link. Thank You!!!

Comment: Besides searching online you can test it quickly yourself with a VS Test project.

Answer (score 2):

For 0-30 or A or D, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/gTU3rs/1)

```
^(([1-2]{0,1}[0-9]{1})|A|D|30)$
```

For 0-25 or A or D, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/7zQyLS/1)

```
^(([1]{0,1}[0-9]{1})|2[0-5]{1}|A|D)$
```

0-20 or A or D should be easily implemented based on the first 0-30...

**EDIT:** Added links to regex as tested in regex101 as per suggestion of Aleks, I didn't know that could be done, Thanks for the tip.

**EDIT:** Link to first solution updated, as it was my first time using that facility, I done messed up!

Comment: Kindly show me how can I write regex for [1 - 20], its not [0 - 20]. Please help!!!

Comment: I think I'd be doing you a disservice if I did that, it's a minor edit to the 0-30 version, if you can see what needs to change it will help you understand how the regex is working.

Comment: @Barry you can save regex you have tested and provide it in your answer (just like I did in mine answer)